# Open window inside a thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, threadpool, task-parallel-library

i need some help how i can manage this problem.

Scenario:

1. Start 3 Threads (each one with different values) (with the TPL or with ThreadPool)
2. Each Thread gather some different data
3. Open foreach thread a Window, with specific data from the thread
4. User enters some value in each window
5. Value is send back to the specific thread
6. Some additional work
7. Finished

Now, the problem is, i can't open a window inside a thread, because it has to be an GUI-Thread (ApartmentState.STA).

Any idea how i can handle the problem with the window / user input?

Comment: You shouldn't let threads wait for user input. That's the root of this problem.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Why would you want to open three windows at the same time? The user won't be able to use all of them at the same time.

Comment: "Now, the problem is, i can't open a window inside a thread" opening a window is already a thread :)

Comment: @svick - that is indeed an issue.  There are several ways to do what the OP wants, but this is a general problem:(  UI windows from other threads tend to pop up while the user is already filling one in, stealing focus and generally annoying the users.  It can be worked around, eg. by using only one form, adding a new frame to a new tabbed page on thread-notification and not taking the focus from the original page - the user can fill in the other pages in turn after filling/OK-ing in the first one.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - yes, in most cases, you are right - UI in the 'middle' of threads is a pain.  Sometimes, however, it is unavoidable.  The app causing me issues now is one such, (though it's Delphi, not C#, but same problem).  It has multiple threads running script interpreter instances, (REMobjects Pascal).  One command is 'GetUserInput()'.  I don't see any other way of implementing that than messaging the UI to create the Edit/RadioButton/List/Checkbox/whatever form and waiting for the user input to be completed before the interpreter thread can 'execute' the next line of script.

Answer (score 2):

http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/

Explains how to setup separate UI-thread for each window.

```
private void OnCreateNewWindow( object sender,   RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
 Window1 w = new Window1();
 w.Show();

 w.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
  w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
});

 thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 thread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to have each thread gather its data, BeginInvoke itself to the GUI thread and then wait on an AutoResetEvent/Semaphore.  The GUI thread gets the message and displays the form/whatever with the data from the thread instance.  The usual component callbacks, (in the GUI thread context), load up the thread members with additional data from user/whatever, then perhaps when the user-entry form is closed or an OK button clicked, signal the event/sema.  The work thread then runs on with the additional user data loaded in.

You don't have to BeginInvoke the thread object  - you could post some other 'ThreadComms' object, if you want, that contains solely the member data and the event to signal.

That's basically one solution that will cetainly work, there are doubtless others.  If you have three threads, it could sometimes get a bit confusing since three user-entry forms could pop up at any time, (annoyingly, new forms from thread/s 2/3 pop up while the user is half-way through filling in a form from thread 1).

You could just Invoke(), but I try to avoid direct, synchronous inter-thread comms if I can.  Invoke() and modal forms may solve the issue of new forms popping up whle the user is busy filling one in.  Maybe you could try that?